# Is there a way to change an array of ints into one single hex number

Tags: arrays, c, hex

So I have been trying to get the LBA of the mbr of a drive. I already found the correct LBA index numbers. The numbers are already in a hex format and I've been assigning them to an array. When I try converting the array to a uint32_t integer in a single hex digit, I'm getting the wrong answer.

This is where I'm getting LBA address:

```
for(i=446;i<512;i++)
{
    fprintf(stdout, "%2x ",b[i]);
  
    if(i == 486 || i == 487 || i == 488 || i == 489)
    {
        //debugging

        LBAAddr[LBAByteNum] = b[i];
        LBAByteNum ++;
    }
}
```

And this where I'm trying to shift the numbers to the left to convert it to a single hex digit.

```
for(int i =0; i< 4; i++)
{
    printf("%2x", nums[i]);
    finalNum = (nums[i] << (8*i+1) ) | nums[i+1];
    
    printf("\n%x", finalNum);
}
```

For example if the for loop prints out 0 0 0 0, I assign it to the array. But when I convert it, I get 4e9052eb.

I'm sorry for the bad formatting, but any help is greatly appreciated!
Thank you!

Comment: It would be better if you could provide a [mre], even if just running on some dummy data. From the tiny snippets you've provided, it seems that `nums[i+1]` might overflow the array. In fact, your second snippet looks completely broken. Your `finalNum` only depends on what it calculates in the last iteration of the loop, and none of the previous iterations.

Answer (score 1):

You need to know the endianess of the array and your uint32_t.

```
uint32_t convert(unsigned char *array, int endianess)
{
    endianess = !!endianess;
    uint32_t result = 0;
    for(size_t index = 0; index < sizeof(result); index++)
    {
        result += ((uint32_t)array[index]) << (24 * endianess + 8 * index * (!endianess * 2 + -1));
    }
    return result;
}


int main(void)
{
    unsigned char arr[] = {0xaa,0xbb,0xcc,0xdd};

    printf("%"PRIx32"\n", convert(arr, 0));
    printf("%"PRIx32"\n", convert(arr, 1));
}
```

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica good spot - typo

Comment: I'm pretty sure LBA values are stored big-endian in MBRs.  If so, it can be converted to a `uint32_t` either with `memcpy()` or type-punning through a `union` and then converted portably with `ntohl()`.  The code would be identical on any platform and no programmer knowledge of the platform endianness would be needed.

Answer (score 0):

You really need to be more specific in your questions:

> So I have been trying to get the LBA of the mbr of a drive.

This is an impossible task. There are 4 partitions in a MBR. Each has its LBA.

> I already found the correct LBA index numbers.

You don't "find" the LBA index numbers. You simply use the locations specified in the standard.

> The numbers are already in a hex format

No, they are not. The numbers are binary, as nearly everything found in your computer.

> and I've been assigning them to an array.

Ok.

> When I try converting the array to a uint32_t integer in a single hex digit, I'm getting the wrong answer.

What do you mean with **in a single hex digit**? The base used to represent your data on screen is totally irrelevant and you definitely don't want "a single hex digit".

It seems that your problem is to convert an array of four `uint8_t` into a single `uint32_t`. Notice that LBAs are stored in little endian. So in your code with `i` from `486` to `489`, the sequence `0a 1b 2c 3d` should be converted in the value `0x3d2c1b0a`. Your code should be something like:

```
uint32_t finalNum = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    finalNum |= nums[i] << (8*i);
}
```

Notice that the `+1` was removed and that you just accumulate on `finalNum`.